# Bowl Shaped magnetic fields responsible to keep galaxies together?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

David LaPoint released some videos on youtube. In part 2 he claims that because galaxies look similar to the shape of plasma created in his experiment they must be shaped also by external magnetic fields.

My question would now be, what generates those fields? It to me looks more like correlation and not causation. I.e. just because something looks similar does not mean it is the result of the same forces.

Has anybody more insight on this?

[Primer Fields 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EPlyiW-xGI)
[Primer Fields 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NogyJ0k8Kw)
[Primer Fields 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpI6ikj1G-s)

Comment: Your thoughts seem more defensible to me than the external magnetic fields hypothesis.  The shape of galaxies is likely more influenced by the gravity effects of dark matter.

Comment: When someone says something looks "similar" it's usually because they haven't done precision measurements which usually destroy any impression of similarity very quickly.

Comment: I don't know either, but what I have seen in the recent literature are some papers claiming they help stabilize clusters, and spiral galaxies. I think there's a lot more modeling and observation left to do, but it might be a factor. Gravity will certainly be the biggest factor. Another paper says they help cluster cores not cool too fast eg http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v6/n7/abs/nphys1657.html.   One paper is just one paper, with a YouTube video or not. Need to research it more is the way I see it.